# Combining images and plots in LevelScheme figures

Tags: plotting, levelscheme

I've found that the `LevelSchemes` package is extremely useful when combining several plots with precise control over where to place legends, making plots withing plots other neat stuff like that, however I ran into problems when I tried to combine a graphics object (like a .png file) and a plot.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a plot depicting the squeezing parameter value in depending on the external electric field strength.
[image: Plot without the picture]

I wanted to obtain something that looks like this:
[image: This is what I want made by hand in a graphics editor (Inkscape)]

To achieve said result I tried something like this:

```
Figure[
 {
  (*Main panel*)
  FigurePanel[
   {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.6, 20}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, FontSize -> 15, 
   LabB -> textit["x"], BufferB -> 2.5, TickFontSize -> 12
   ],
  DataPlot[
   dati, Tag -> set[1]
   ],
  ScaledLabel[{0.5, 0.2}, 
   "some value=" <> 
    ToString[Some expression that returns a number], 
   FontSize -> 13],

 (*Smaller Pannel*)
  ScaledFigurePanel[
   {{0, 0.55}, {0.55, 0.95}},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}
   ],
   (*AMPSPlot is essentially SphericalPlot3D that takes a nxn matrix as an argument.
   It is found in the ADM package*)
  RawGraphics[
   Rasterize[
    Axes3D[AMPSPlot[
      WignerRotate[
       gdm[Flatten[sols[[30, 2]]]], {optlen[
         gdm[Flatten[sols[[30, 2]]]]], 0, 0}], PlotRange -> All, 
      Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]]]]

  },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.1}, {-0.2, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 100*{6, 4}

 ]
```

but I get something like this:
[image: "This doesn't work at all"]

Is there any way to incoorporate pictures in graphics by `LevelScheme`? The main goal I am trying to do this is to see how the graphs look every time I tweak which set of parameters I've used, without going through the fiddly process of merging them in Inkscape.

Comment: Have you looked at `Inset`? It lets you specify where in a figure you want things (like your 3D graphic and your equation) to appear.

Comment: I have only recently started working with 'LevelScheme' so I am not sure how to use `Inset` in that context and I would like to stick to the `LevelScheme` environment if possible. My problem with `Inset` is that it's coordinates are tied to those of the plot rather to the absolute coordinates of the frame (I think that's what's going on, I've had trouble positioning with `Inset`).

Comment: If you look under "Details and Options" for `Inset` there are many ways to specify the coordinates.

Comment: You are, of course, right. For the time being I will probably try using standard Mathematica plotting tools and inset, but I am still curious whether it is possible to combine pictures and plots in `LevelScheme` as well. Thank you for the advice though!

Comment: Take a look at the [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) which is the successor of LevelScheme.  In the Examples-Tutorial.nb notebook that comes with the package you'll find an example precisely like what you are looking for.  I was a latercomer to LevelScheme and I never properly learned it, so I can't help you with that package, but with SciDraw it's quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it with the [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), which is the successor of LevelScheme (you'll be able to re-use some of what you've learned about LevelScheme).  I'm not experienced with the original LevelScheme so I won't attempt to use it now or comment on its capabilities.

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]

Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigLine@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

   FigInset[Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Boxed -> False], 
       Scaled[{{0.5, 1}, {0.5, .95}}]];
  },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 2 Pi}, YPlotRange -> 1.1 {-1, 1}
 ]
]
```

[image]

The key was using `FigInset`.  Just like with `Inset`, you can include practically anything that can appear in a notebook.

You'll find a similar but more detailed example of the same in the `Examples-Tutorial.nb` notebook that comes with the package.

Comment: Thank you, after trying `SciDraw` I have to admit that both the documentation is much more complete (the guide is excellent compared to the one for `LevelScheme`) and there are many more things you can do in it than in `LevelScheme`.